# addClass to li smoothscroll this.hash

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have some hashed links on a page, that im trying to get a class added to once the link is clicked.

The smoothScroll i have is working great, and even adding the class, but its adding the class to EVERY li element. How can i target the selected hash li element and add a class to that ONLY.

```js
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          $('#subNavMain li').addClass('active');
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex', '-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
            console.log(target);
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#top-review-expressVPN1">#1 - ExpressVPN <span class="badge">10/10</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#top-review-expressVPN2">#2 - ExpressVPN <span class="badge">9/10</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please update with relevant HTML to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class to `$(this)` which is the object passed through in the `.click()` function. For example:

```
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          $(this).addClass('active');
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex', '-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
            console.log(target);
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi Oli, thanks for the suggestion, i gave this a whirl, makes a lot of sense! Its just adding the active class to the HTML and body tags though, rather than the link i click?! :-s

Comment: Hmm that is interesting! Without a code snippet, can't say for sure what is happening there, as `$(this)` should equal `$('a[href*="#"]').not('[href="#"]').not('[href="#0"]')` that the click event has happened against.

It looks like you are saving the current clicked element as `target` however, so instead of `$(this).addClass('active')`, try using `target.addClass('active')` to see if this does what you want to achieve.